Lookup field in Sharepoint Online list with saved values
I have a list in Sharepoint Online with a column contains counterparty names. The type of this column is Single Line.
I would like to give possiblity for users in New item form to choose counterparty name from already saved ones.
It's possible to add a new Lookup column and connect it to that Single Line column.
In this case there will be 2 columns with the same values.
I didn't find possibility to have only one Lookup column that get data from itself.
Is this the only option with 2 columns?
Thanks

I do not think you can do this using the out of the box list forms, you can customize the using Power Apps, which will allow you to have a dropdown list inside the form then you can pass the drop down selection into your single line.

Thank you for your response. I resolved this problem by moving counterparty fields to another list and making connections between Contracts and Counterparties lists.
